# probability distribution of the winning amount

Tags: probability, statistics

Be A_n the event that a worker spends to process certain component with probabilities according to the table below:

[image]

For each piece processed, the worker earns a fixed US 2.00, but if he processes the component in less than 6 minutes wins US 0.50 for each minute spared. For example, if he processes the component in four minutes, he receives the additional amount of US 1.00.
Find the probability distribution of the winning amount. What is P (L≥ 2.5)?

Guys, could you help me here. I do not know how to start...

Comment: If she does it in $2$ min. she gets $4$ dollars. So if $X$ is the amount earned, then $\Pr(X=4)=0.1$. Similarly, $\Pr(X=3.5)=0.1$. Things continue like that, except she gets $2$ dollars if she takes $6$ or $7$ minutes, so $\Pr(X=2)=0.3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording of your question is a bit vague. My guess is you
want the distribution of a random variable $L$ that takes
values as in the table below.

```
 Min  L      Prob
  2   4.00   .1
  3   3.50   .1
  4   3.00   .3
  5   2.50   .2
  6   2.00   .2
  7   2.00   .1
```

Maybe you can take it from there.

Comment: Essentially the same as hint from @AndreNicholas which appeared while I was answering (interrupted by a phone call). Can you add the appropriate probabilities for $P(L \ge 2.50$? Next step along this path of exploring random variables, not yet asked, would be to find the expected value of $L$, often denoted as $E(L)$ or $\mu_L.$

Comment: Is it not the sum 0.7?

Comment: Yes. Indeed so.